# Does Linq produces redundancies?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, linqpad

I refer to the Examples in [How to: Combin Data with Linq by using joins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb918093.aspx). We have two Lists the first holds person objects (First- and Lastname). The second List holds Pet objects (Name) that holds a person object (pet owner). One Person can own >= 0 pets.

What happend now is I performed the group join

```
Dim result1 = From pers in people
            Group Join pet in pets
            on pers Equals pet.Owner
            Into PetList = Group
```

LinqPad shows me the result:

[image: LinqPad Output]

This looks to me like Linq is producing a lot of redundancies (but I might be wrong here!). The first result object would hold the person object three times. Two questions arises here for me as a Linq nooby (but maybe I read the output not the right way):

1. Are the person objects references? Unfortunately I couldnt find anything about it.
2. Following the example mentioned above the query continues with

> ```
> Select pers.FirstName , pers.LastName,
> PetName = If(pet is Nothing, String.Empty, pet.Name)
> ```

If we have all information about the Person Object in the PetList, why not just query this object? In my opinion we dont need the pers Object anymore.

Comment: I think the key facts here are linq uses deferred execution and this should get compiled into a format that means these redundancies are not created (as much as possible)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, those Person objects are references. LINQ is not cloning Person objects.

The reason for that output is that LINQPad is trying to show you who that person is. Without repeating a walk of its properties and fields, it would be hard to tell what person it was referring to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This means, that LINQPad show the Key=Person object but it is not in the acutal object generated in .NET? I just checked that, there is only an Pet and an Owner property in PetList. I get the intention, but it is still confusing.